# How to define a range for each key in array dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array:

```
$var = array('a', 'b');
```

Now I want to define a range for each key. For example:

**5 keys set on each value of array:**

```
echo $var[0]; // output: a
echo $var[1]; // output: a
echo $var[2]; // output: a
echo $var[3]; // output: a
echo $var[4]; // output: a

echo $var[5]; // output: b
echo $var[6]; // output: b
echo $var[7]; // output: b
echo $var[8]; // output: b
echo $var[9]; // output: b
```

In fact I want something like this:

```
$var = array( '0'=>'a', '1'=>'a', '2'=>'a', '3'=>'a', '4'=>'a',
              '5'=>'b', '6'=>'b', '7'=>'b', '8'=>'b', '9'=>'b'  );
```

But in reality I can not define a rage of keys for each value, because the values are too much. It should be noted that I can implement it via `if-else` statement *(without `array`)*, But in this case, performance will drop dramatically. something like this:

```
if      (0 <= $i <=4) { $var = 'a'; }
elseif  (5 <= $i <=9) { $var = 'b'; }
```

But as I said, the values are too much and I can not define a range for each value manually. So there is any solution ? *(set 5 keys for each value dynamically)*

Comment: Does each value have equal share over the keys? In that case, you can just calculate, for given N values, which Nth part of the keys a certain key belongs to. So for three values (N=3) A will be [0;max/N[, B will be [max/N;2*max/N[ and C will be [2*max/N;3*max/N[.

Comment: @klaar your mean is: `array('a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b');` ?

Comment: See the edit of my previous comment; posting this in case you missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr = array('a', 'b');
$i = 6; // for e.g.
$var = $arr[floor($i/5)];

// output: b
```

Comment: just why `$i=6`, I think `5` is fine, is it not ?

Comment: $i may be 0 <= $i <= 9

Comment: ok, how about 10 keys for each value? `$i=11;` and `floor($i/10);` ? that's correct ?

Comment: @Sajad I've written `$i=6;` only for testing. It is index for which you want to get value

Comment: sorry for asking again, how can I select last value for a number out of range ? consider this: `0 <= $i <= 9`, so I want to select last value for `$i=10`, is it possible ?

Comment: `$interval = 5; $i = $i >= 2*$interval ? $interval : $i;`

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Just loop through your array and [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) your result array with each value as many times as you want, e.g.

```
<?php

    $var = array('a', 'b');
    $amount = 5;
    $result = [];

    foreach($var as $k => $v)
        $result = $result + array_fill($k*$amount, $amount, $v);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => a
    [2] => a
    [3] => a
    [4] => a
    [5] => b
    [6] => b
    [7] => b
    [8] => b
    [9] => b
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = array( '0'=>'a', '1'=>'b');

$new_array = array();
foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
    for($i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++){
        $new_array[] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_array);
```